# Regular Expression to fetch some part of text from given string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm learning Regular expressions and I want to achieve something like this

I have a string as follows

```
1. https://www.example.com/abc23?xyz&mnop=12ab&productid=qwerty123
2. https://www.example.com/abc23?xyz&mnop=12ab&productid=hai456&someAlphaNumeric=0987
3. https://www.example.com/abc23?xyz&mnop=12ab&productid=bye789&asdf=0987
```

Now I want to get productid parameter including '&' from the URL's.

This is the expected output

```
1. &productid=qwerty123
2. &productid=hai456
3. &productid=bye789
```

Comment: please add what you have tried and what does not work.

Comment: Do not parse URLs with regexp. Use a URL library.

Answer (score 0):

You can match "&productid=" directly but the remaining part is variable. To match any word character, use "\w+" ('+' to match at least one and more) like "&productid=\w+". '&' will not be matched as it is a special charachter. '\w' will take only [a-zA-Z0-9]

So final regex would be : &productid=\w+

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/ww5on8/1)

This will match what you need. Remember, this is just one way, there can be other regex also to get same result.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/7gtxqJ/3). Your regex matches the last character an additional time (in capture group 1).

Comment: Yes it was capturing last character again. Modified the regex, now it works fine and it is much simpler. Check the Live Example.

Comment: `&productid=ha()i456` this should be matched. But it isn't.

Comment: product id is not going to have (). it will be words and numbers.

Comment: we don't know that. That is never expressed by OP in the post.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it: `&productid=.*?(?=[&\n]|$)`

[Live Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7gtxqJ/2)

- `&productid=` will match the exact text **&productid=**
- `.*?` will match anything but a newline lazily (aka with the least ammout of characters possible)
- `(?=[&\n]|$)` is a positive look-ahead for either an `&` sign, a new line or the end of the string

---

```
const regex = /&productid=.*?(?=[&\n]|$)/g;
const str = `
https://www.example.com/abc23?xyz&mnop=12ab&productid=qwerty123
https://www.example.com/abc23?xyz&mnop=12ab&productid=hai456&someAlphaNumeric=0987
https://www.example.com/abc23?xyz&mnop=12ab&productid=bye789&asdf=0987`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```